# How to extract json_decode array element value from cURL

Tags: php, arrays, json, curl

What I am trying to do is to get the value of the first element, `[0]['uri']` from my result curl api. I have an associative array from the `curl_exec` but can't figure out how to extract the data to find the value of the first element.  I have tried `echo $alerts[0]['uri']` but it doesn't work.

```
<?php

//  Initiate curl
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: application/json',"Authorization: Bearer $access_token"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);

$alerts = json_decode($result,true);
print_r($alerts);
//echo $alerts[0]['uri'] doesn't work.

?>
```

Output Result:

```
Array (
    [result] => success
    [message] => Array (
        [alerts] => Array (
            [0] => Array (
                [id] => 78591963
                [uri] => htps://access.rrr.com/interface/open_api/api/alerts/78591963
            )
            [1] => Array (
                [id] => 78576283
                [uri] => htps://access.rrr.com/interface/open_api/api/alerts/78576283
            )
            [2] => Array (
                [id] => 78576209
                [uri] => htps://access.rrr.com/interface/open_api/api/alerts/78576209
            )
            [3] => Array (
                [id] => 78572644
                [uri] => htps://access.rrr.com/interface/open_api/api/alerts/78572644
            )
            [4] => Array
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Try this : `$alerts['messages']['alerts'][0]['uri'] `

Comment: it looks like it is inside the `message` and `alerts`, so `$alerts['messages']['alerts'][0]['uri']`

Comment: that doesn't work, i tried $alerts['alerts'][0]['uri'] no luck either. The [result], [message] are the http header of curl by the way

Comment: Try this one: `$alerts['message']['alerts'][0]['uri']`

Comment: actually, it did work. [message] without the s at the end. But anyways, thank you guys so much.

Answer (score 0):

Answer was given by other gentlemen in the comment. 
I failed to look at the array structure. It is simply: 
`$alerts['message']['alerts'][0]['uri']`